# Unique User Profiles via URL

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Alright, i've asked this question in the past. However, when I asked it, I had a limited knowledge of python and app engine. This is most likely why I failed to implement this in the past. I'm attempting to get each profile to be unique based on the username.

Any who, before I dive in, i'll throw my profile handler up that only deals with currently logged in users at the moment:

```
class Profile(MainHandler):
    def get(self):
        if self.user:
            current_user = str(self.user.name)
            key = ''
            imgs  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Profile_Images WHERE name =:1", current_user)
            team_name  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Teams WHERE name =:1", current_user)
            team_images  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Teamimg WHERE user =:1", current_user)
        for clan in team_name:
                name1 = clan.team_name_anycase
        for image in team_images:
            team_imagee = image.key()
        if self.user:
            for img in imgs:
                key = img.key()
            self.render('profile.html', team_img = team_imagee, team_name = name1, profile_image = key, username = self.user.name, email = self.user.email, firstname = self.user.first_name, last_name = self.user.last_name, country = self.user.country)
        else:
            self.redirect('/register')
```

This handler is mapped via ('profile', Profile).

Any who, what I understand thus far is that I need to pass the username through the URL and into the profile handler which then uses that username as identifier for pulling data from the db.

What I saw posted on stackoverflow was `('profile/<profile_id>', Profile)`. And I have been messing around with that for a bit, but it seems that the trailing username (ex.localhost:8080/profile/admin) is getting a 404 error. I would assume that either my mapping is failing, or the variable (i.e. the username) is failing to interact with the profile handler.

Could someone please help me out here? I was sure I had it, and it failed.

**YAML file:**

```
application: suitegamer
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /img
  static_dir: img

- url: /.*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: jinja2
  version: latest

- name: PIL
  version: "1.1.7"
```

**MainHandler:**

```
class MainPage(MainHandler):
    def get(self):
    if self.user:
            self.render('index.html', username = self.user.name, firstname = self.user.first_name)
        else:
            self.render('index.html')

    def post(self):
    username = self.request.get('username').lower()
        password = self.request.get('password')

        u = User.login(username, password)
        if u:
            self.login(u)
            self.redirect('/news_page')
        else:
            msg = 'Invalid login.'
            self.render('login.html', error = msg)
```

**Mapping:**

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/logout', Logout),
                               ('/img', GetImage),
                               ('/register', Register),
                               ('/welcome', Welcome),
                               ('/news_page', News_Page),
                               ('/profile', Profile),
                               ('/edit_profile', Edit_Profile),
                               ('/change_profile_image', Change_Profile_Image),
                               ('/found_a_team', Found_Team),
                               ('/team_main', Team_Main),
                               ('/edit_team_main', Edit_Team_Main),
                               ('/edit_team_image', Edit_Team_Image)],
                              debug=True)
```

**Testing Profile Handler:**

```
class Profile(MainHandler):
    def get(self, profile_id):
        profile_id = 'admin'
        if self.user:
            key = ''
            imgs  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Profile_Images WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
            team_name  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Teams WHERE name =:1", profile_id)
            team_images  = db.GqlQuery("select * from Teamimg WHERE user =:1", profile_id)
        for clan in team_name:
                name1 = clan.team_name_anycase
        for image in team_images:
            team_imagee = image.key()
        if self.user:
            for img in imgs:
                key = img.key()
            self.render('profile.html', team_img = team_imagee, team_name = name1, profile_image = key, username = self.user.name, email = self.user.email, firstname = self.user.first_name, last_name = self.user.last_name, country = self.user.country)
        else:
            self.redirect('/register')
```

Image Handler:

```
class GetImage(MainHandler):
    def get(self):
        img = db.get(self.request.get("entity_id"))
        self.response.out.write(img.image)
```

Maps to ('/img', GetImage)

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what isn't working in your current code?

Comment: This code only renders the profile of the person logging in via the mapping to /profile. If you log in as admin, your profile is the admins. If you log in as say, Jeff, the visible profile is Jeff's.

Comment: Is the problem that you want a user to be able to view other users' profiles? e.g. /profile/<some_username>  would render a different user's details?

Comment: are you using webapp/webapp2 or django or something else? please show app.yaml, your MainHandler and url mapping.

Comment: wepapp2 and django templates. The <profile_id> at the end of /profile/<profile_id>. Is that essentially a variable that can be passed in to the profile handler? If I can figure out how to pass data from the url to the handler, I think I'll be ok.

Comment: please update your question with the missing parts i asked above otherwise its a little hard to help you. i have some ideas but i don't want to guess.

Comment: i was speaking about `MainHandler` not `MainPage` but it doesn't matter at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the mapping should look like this:

```
('/profile/(.*)/?', Profile)
```

and your Handlers get function should take a parameter which will be the profile id/name

```
class Profile(MainHandler):
    def get(self, profile_id):
        # do something with the profile id...
```

i think you should give the docs a deeper look.
for example here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/running

Comment: Ill give it a whirl. Thank you very much. I'll save that documents page.

Comment: I'm getting a 404. I've edited my post with the handler I attempted to use with ('profile/(.*)/?', Profile). I also tried it with ('profile/(.*)', Profile). This is exactly what was happening before. For testing purposes, I made profile_id = 'admin', an account on my db.

Comment: sorry there was a typo on my answer. there was the leading `/` missing in the mapping. `/profile/(.*)/?` not `profile/(.*)/?`

Comment: the trailing `/?` makes the slash at the end optional so the mapping matches `/profile/admin` and also `/profile/admin/`

Comment: I'm not sure how I missed that haha. Alright, its loading profiles now. I just have to tweak it to pull data based on the profile_id. I think its time for a gym break. Thank you very much sir. You were most helpful!

Comment: Everything is working now except for my images. Which is odd seeing as when you check the source code, you see this:

<div id="profile_image_profile_page"><img src="img?entity_id=ag5kZXZ-c3VpdGVnYW1lcnIYCxIOUHJvZmlsZV9JbWFnZXMiBGtyaXMM" width="200" height="200"/></div>

The key, but its not being rendered. Its not a much right now, just odd behavior. I'll shove my image handler in the post. Don't worry about it if your busy.

Comment: did you maybe try to add a trailing `/` in the img src? ;)

Comment: if you check your app.yaml you are matching `/img` to a static handler which obviously doesn't touch your handler. but the trailing slash issue still remains.

Comment: Hm, I guess I'm missing something simple here. Sorry I was out for a bit. The img handler was working just fine with /profile, but is failing with /profile/admin. I'm not entirely sure what is causing that. I think I may be missing something with your comments above... I still don't see why it would fail... hm... Why would a trailing slash make a difference? Forgive my ... lack of knowledge lol.

Comment: if you are not setting a trailing slash the url is relative to the urlpath you are at that specific page. so if you are at `/profile/admin` and set a relative url in the template as `img` it will resolve in `/profile/adminimg`

Comment: Yup, I did some reading and figured it out. Thanks a ton. I've learned a lot today. Cheers!