# Xamarin Android User Profile Web URL

Tags: c#, url, xamarin, xamarin.android, user-profile

I am trying to make a social media type app for Xamarin Android. Let's say I have an activity that shows my profile information and I have added one friend. How would I be able to navigate to that profile just from clicking his name? In a website such as Facebook, there is a profile URL that I can call a GET request from the webserver and I get HTML and JavaScript and can populate my browser with that information.

In my app, I'm guessing that I would have to have my web server generate a profile URL and .axml code that will serve as the layout for the activity. Is this right? If so, where can I find the resources to do such a thing.

I read this post and it's kind of similar to what I'm doing: [Unique User Profiles via URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11837620/unique-user-profiles-via-url)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you mentioned about creating a web server is correct. However, the web server will not pass the `.axml` code for android app client.

In short, technically what you need is just a database. However, an online app, like social media in your case, will need to have an app database that hosted in the internet, in order to serve the data needed by the app. Therefore, you could conclude the architecture used in this case is client-server, in which your Android app acts as the client. In client-server architecture, it is best to use web service layer so the client could not have direct SQL access to the database (security). Not only that, it also brings other benefits. I will not going to be specific about it as it is not the topic here, but if you would like to know, check this [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/170470). Anyway, you could say the web service will act like a bridge between client and server. It could be developed in `Node.js` (`JavaScript`), `php`, or any other server-side languages.

Now, the web server, instead of passing the `.axml`, it will pass only the data (usually in `JSON`). So, what you will do is develop the `.axml` for the screens, then on your Android app activities or PCL (if you used `MvvmCross` framework), you could do HTTP `GET` or `POST` to your web service's endpoint to perform CRUD.

Hope this answer could help you.